# How to migrate from HTML_QuickForm to HTML_QuickForm2

Tags: php, pear

I'm PHP noob!

I'm doing version up very old PHP system to PHP5.

It is using many pear API.

This is old source

```
$form = new HTML_QuickForm("commonForm", "POST", "controller.php");
$form->addElement("text", "empNo", "UserNo", array("autocomplete" => "off"));
$form->addElement("password", "empPass", "Password");
$form->display();
```

And the result

[image]

So i changed my source with this link.
http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform2.qf-migration.php

And this is my new source.

```
$form = new HTML_QuickForm2("commonForm", "POST", "controller.php");
$form->addElement("text", "empNo", array("autocomplete" => "off"))
->setLabel('UserNo');
$form->addElement("password", "empPass")
->setLabel('Password');

echo $form;
```

This is result

[image]

I want to make same old version.

Can i get some teaching?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The PEAR manual has a complete section about migrating to HTML_QuickForm2, see http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform2.qf-migration.php